# xgboost or lightgbm to handle Binomial problems

Tags: xgboost, probability, hyperparameter

I have a dataset containing a column of trials, a column of successes and other features; and, obviously, I can generate a probability column. I would like to use gradient boosting methods (like xgboost or lightgbm) to model the success probability. Which parameter shall I set to handle this in lightgbm or xgboost?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible with the main (as I can tell) xgboost library, because this essentially sounds like a regression on rates/proportions situation (a dependent variable bounded in [0,1]).

An easy way to have implemented this would have been to allow the [Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) (see how it is bounded) as an objective function in [xgboost](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html), but it is not an option at this point.

Answer (score 0):

There are beta regression models for [R](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MXM/versions/0.9.7/topics/Beta%20regression) and [Python](https://gist.github.com/brentp/089c7d6d69d78d26437f). They are designed to handle values between 0 and 1. However, as far as I'm aware, there is no direct beta regression implementation with LightGBM, XGboost etc. Some folks seem to expand beta regression into [tree-based approaches](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/betareg/vignettes/betareg-ext.pdf), but this is not equivalent to boosting.

Also see [this post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/57023/71442) for a very similar problem. As mentionned there, a naive approach could be to simply run a normal regression in a boosting setup and see how "bad" the results are (i.e. values $<0$ and $>1$). Alternatively you could try to predict the continuous features and calculate the success probability from predicted values.